# Using random module in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

With start command in discord I'm getting a list of users from author voice channel and store them inside a list and remove song bots and other relevant bots from this list cause I need only users (persons not bots).

After change their id to their names mention one of them randomly and save that inside a variable (`userchoosed`) like this:

```
userchoosed = ""
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    channelVoice = ctx.author.voice.channel #getting author voice channel

    member_ids = channelVoice.members #finds members connected to the channel

    ids = [] #empty list
    for member in member_ids:
        ids.append(member.mention) #change the member's id to their names and list them in ids[]
    
    listToRemove = ['<@!547905866255433758>','<@!234395307759108106>','<@!614109280508968980>','<@!806618501041225728>','<@!228537642583588864>','<@!184405311681986560>','<@!428655825817567261>']
    finalList = list(set(ids) - set(listToRemove)) #final list is a list without bots with above ids
    print(finalList) #just to see the result until this line of code
    await ctx.send("`` Lets go! ``")
    userchoosed = random.choice(finalList)
    await ctx.send(userchoosed)
    global listTouse #making a global list of Final list to use it again in other command
    listTouse = finalList
```

ok now we have a variable with a random user.

Now I want to mention another user but not equal the previous user cause I don't want a user to be called twice in a row randomly so I make it by this:

```
@client.command()
async def next(ctx):
    user = random.choice(listTouse) #making this variable for storing another user from list
    while userchoosed == user: #check if this random user equal userchoosed(the previous user)
        user = random.choices(listTouse) #again store another random user
        userchoosed == user #change the userchoosed to user for the next time member use this command
    await ctx.send(user)#and finally mention user
```

I tried these but again I get same user mention twice in a row What is the problem??

Answer (score 0):

In the second code snippet you want to change `userchoosed` to `user`, but you actually change `user` back to `userchoosed` in the second last line. Changing this should give you the result you want.

Comment: oh so i should say  userchoosed = user?

Comment: Yes, at the moment you're just setting user to the new choice, and then setting user to the old choice once again.

Comment: I changed it in the correct form but it still dont work properly

Comment: Do you have an example of how you are using these commands in discord?

Comment: so its a truth and dare bot and start with --start then the bot send "Lets go" and mention one user for start the game user can chose truth or dare with commands --truth --dare and bot randomly show them on sentence after this somebody type --next for next user and the bot mention the next one this is why I dont want a user to be called  twise in a row.now bot mention i.e. "name" and again after --next it mention "name" again and I dont want this to happen. I hope this is what you want to know

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted to know! I think I noticed another problem with your `next` command though:

The while loop checks: `userchoosed` is equal to `user`, but in the last line of that loop we set `userchoosed` to `user`, the while loop should never terminate because `userchoosed` will always be equal to `user`. To fix this you can try moving the `userchoosed = user` line to outside of the loop, so on the same level as the `await ctx.send(...` line

Comment: thank you really much for your help I tried that but it still doesn't work properly.this time I put a print inside the while loop to check if this loop work but I didnt get the print even once but we should actually see that print in terminal every time we use the next command no?

Comment: absolutely! that means that the loop is never run, so `userchoosed` is not equal to `user` at the very beginning, you can try testing the print debug outside of the loop to to be sure that the function is run at all